# Using onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) to change view to a different Tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, fragment

I have an app that has 4 (0,1,2,3) Tabs and Fragments. My Actionbar has a menu item called "settings". When settings is clicked I want to navigate from the current Tab/Fragment to Fragment(3). In each of my java files associated with a fragment I am using the code below to handle menu clicks. I can launch an Intent successfully with this code but how can I navigate to another tab/fragment on menu item click? Thanks!

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.new_game:
            newGame();
            return true;
        case R.id.help:
            showHelp();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My actual code.

```
public class event extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return view;
}
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.notify:
                Log.i("4", "Notify pressed");
                return true;

            case R.id.action_settings:
                Log.i("4", "Settings pressed");
                return true;

            default:
                // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
                // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.custom_menu, menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a `ViewPager`? If so `viewPager.setCurrentItem(3)`

Comment: I am using viewPager but I get this error when I tried what you suggested.  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: That indicates that the variable you are calling `setCurrentItem(3)` on is null. Are you using the correct id when you find the `ViewPager` with `findViewById` ? See my answer for a simple code example.

Comment: I know I am missing ViewPager code in the Class but i'm not sure what. Can you explain what other code is needed for the ViewPager and findViewById ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `ViewPager` then it's as simple as [`setCurrentItem(int currentItem)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem%28int%29)

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // ...
        case R.id.settings:
            ((ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.of_view_pager)).setCurrentItem(3);
            return true;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Edit in response to:

> When I add that code some elements show up in red indicating I am doing something wrong. "findViewById" and "of_view_pager" are in red.

Sounds like you are in a `Fragment` and not an `Activity` in which case you probably want to find the `ViewPager` in your `onCreateView` method and store it in a field for later use in your `onOptionsItemSelected` method.

Something like this:

```
private ViewPager m_viewPager;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_changelog, container, false);

    // Other stuff already in your `onCreateView`

    m_viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.of_view_pager);

    return view;
}
```

The `of_view_pager` is in red because that id doesn't exist. You need to replace it with the correct id of your `ViewPager` that you specified in the layout.

Comment: When I add that code some elements show up in red indicating I am doing something wrong. "findViewById" and "of_view_pager" are in red. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcusRey see my update. I'm only giving a general idea of what you need to achieve. You'll need to tailor it to your own application.

Comment: Thanks, when I try that code "of_view_pager" appears in red. What is of_view_pager trying to reference?

Comment: @MarcusRey that is the is of your ViewPager that you specified in your layout.

Comment: I think i'm getting pretty close but I am still getting an error. findViewById appears in red in the following code ((ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager)).setCurrentItem(3); , with Cannot resolve method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know where I went wrong. I had a main activity and a fragment for each tab in my application. I had two action bar menus one included in the main activity and one custom menu for fragments. The code I was trying to run for switching tabs by clicking a menu button did not work if the onOptionsItemSelected code was in the fragment file. When I put the code in the main activity it worked fine.